# Comparing nullable DateTime's in VB.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am a c#/asp.net developer and I am having to work on a VB/asp.net. 
I started out with VB.NET but after years away from it I'm getting confused with the syntax.

I have two variables

```
Dim originalDate as DateTime?
Dim newDate as DateTime?
```

Both nullable datetimes, originalDate is a nullable date I am getting from the database and newDate time is set in code, I need to compare them, they can either both have dates, neither have dates or one have and one not.

I have a bit of code as follows:

```
if origEndDate = origEndDate then
```

When both origEndDate and origEndDate are "nothing" this statement is false (well when I run it in the watch window it comes back as nothing)!

I don't understand why this is the case because I was under the impression doing an "=" compares the two values and as they are the same surely it should be true?

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? What syntax should I be using as in C# I can do the above as so:

```
if (origEndDate == origEndDate) { }
```

and it will come back as true.

Confused!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `originalDate.Equals(newDate)` maybe?

(No, this will not cause an NRE when either date is null, since the variables are actually of the *value type* `Nullable(Of DateTime)` and are therefore not *actually* null until they are boxed.)

Comment: What's an NRE? both this method and object.equals(originalDate ,newDate ) works.. which should I be using?

Comment: NullReferenceException.  I would use this method, since it will use the override on the `Nullable(Of DateTime)` type, which will be faster than using the default reflection-based comparison of value types.

Comment: that makes sense..! But how come the straight forward "=" doesn't work as it does in c# (well == in c#)?

Comment: @Bex, under vb.net, to check if something is null (nothing) you need to do: if obj is nothing then

Comment: or, with nullable object you can try .hasvalue to know if anything is set

Comment: let not start a language war :-p , in the end, it's CLR :-)

Comment: @Fredou: Not trying to start a language war, just noticing the number of "VB does this weird thing I didn't expect" questions on SO is a **lot** higher than the ones for C#.  ;)

Comment: :) must admit I used to sing the praises of VB against C#, but now I've gone back to it for this proj I'm struggling! (also may be because Resharper works much better with C#!!)

Answer (score 2):

use object.equals(originalDate ,newDate )

Comment: this works but so does the answer below, does it make any difference in this case what type of variables both the originalDate and newDate are, as in can I use it in other placesor just for nullables?

Comment: @Bex, I would need to look with reflector how the .Equals on type of date work but I think it's just calling Object.Equals, Object.Equals would work with ANY kind of object

Comment: `object.Equals` will work in any case.  You only really need it when either parameter may be null (except in the case of unboxed nullables, which are never *actually* null).  Otherwise, using the `.Equals()` method on one of the objects will be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks both for your help! Sounds like the one below is the answer.. but I will do some testing with a few values before I mark one.

Answer (score 2):

Using GetValueOrDefault will handle the case when both dates are null

```
Dim d1 As New Nullable(Of DateTime)
Dim d2 As New Nullable(Of DateTime)
If d1.GetValueOrDefault = d2.GetValueOrDefault Then
  {do stuff}
End If
```

Otherwise, you could check a combination of HasValue to sort out when the dates are undefined.

```
If (Not d1.HasValue AndAlso Not d1.HasValue) OrElse (d1.HasValue AndAlso d2.HasValue AndAlso d1 = d2) Then
  {do stuff}
End If
```

Comment: So what would be the default value for the Integer nullable? 0? Does that mean that if my object does not have a value I would get a 0 when I use GetValueOrDefault?

Answer (score 1):

I found that Date.Equals does work for equality but there arn't any methods for other operators (< or > for example).

If you need to compare for greater or less than you need to use:

```
If Date1.GetValueOrDefault > Date2.GetValueOrDefault Then
    ...
End If
```

I have decided to standardize all my code to use this method for consistency's sake.
So now my equality checks have the same format as the example above:

```
If Date1.GetValueOrDefault = Date2.GetValueOrDefault Then
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Nullable Class methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable_methods(v=vs.90).aspx) when you need to know if two Nullables are equal

```
Dim d1 As New Nullable(Of DateTime)
Dim d2 As New Nullable(Of DateTime)
Dim result As String = "Not Equal"
If( Nullable.Equals(d1,d2))
    result = "Equal"
End If
```

Also you can check greater than, less than

```
Dim compareResult As Integer
compareResult = Nullable.Compare(d1,d2)
If(compareResult > 0)
    result = "d1 greater than d2"
Else If (compareResult < 0)
    result = "d1 less than d2"
Else
    result = "d1 equal d2"
End If
```